# How is UEFI pronounced?

Tags: bios, uefi

UEFI stands for unified extensible firmware interface. Most people know about BIOS (Basic Input/Output System) and to my knowledge pronounce it universal as 'by-ohs'. I've looked around for the pronunciation of UEFI and have seen it pronounced:

- Yoo-fee
- Ooh-fee
- U-E-F-I
- Ü-fee

What is the most commonly used pronounciation and the originally intended pronunciation, if it differs from the common pronunciation. (Such as in .gif—`/ɡɪf/` vs. `/dʒɪf/`)

Comment: This question would probably invite opinion-based answers, but what it asks for is statistics on usage or a similar factual answer (which may not fit within the scope of the site in terms of subject matter).  @matan provided exactly such a fact based, direct answer, quoting from a reference.

Comment: English pronunciation is not a software or hardware issue

Comment: @random isn't it english pronunciation of a software/hardware? Assuming that this question wasn't 'opinion-based' where would it have been best suited for?

Comment: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/608/when-are-questions-about-pronunciation-acceptable

Comment: But yes, asking about pronunciation would be like asking where stickers should be placed on a laptop

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface):

> The Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI) (pronounced as an initialism U-E-F-I or like "unify" without the n)*
>
> *Various pronunciations have existed for UEFI; according to the UK PC Pro Magazine, the following pronunciations are in use: "weffy" (PC Pro), "U-E-F-I" (Microsoft), "you-fee", and "you-ef-fee". It is also mentioned that there is no agreement on the pronunciation